# Why is Henry Jones Jr. named Indiana?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, analysis, indiana-jones

In the movie series Indiana Jones, the title character is often called by *Indiana Jones* or just *Indy*. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indiana_Jones#cite_note-34), Dr. Jones' full name is **Henry Walton Jones Jr.**.

I understand that Indiana could be a nickname that stuck on. Is there any indication in the movie series or any other in-universe source for why he's named Indiana or how he came to be known as Indiana? If so, when was this?

Comment: I always thought it had to do with the state Indiana.

Comment: I'm going to have to downvote this one for not showing any research effort. Your answer is actually *in the article you linked*.

Comment: See also [Why does Henry Jones Jr. uses the nickname Indiana?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/183606/44383) over at [scifi.SE]

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, I've fgot two different theories from that. The Dog's name reference and some other reference that Jones family were from Indiana and because Henry was very common name, he got stuck with the name Indiana, his home state

Comment: @mathreadler The scifi SE link that Bergi provided states another answer that supports what you thought of. As for now, I cannot verify that answer because ot hasn't included any references to support that answer

Comment: I agree with @T.J.L., you haven't done much research as the reason is in one of the films !

Comment: @Neil Just because the reason is in the films doesn't mean there was a lack of research - many questions here are answered directly in the film itself.  The lack of research here is because OP literally had the answer in his hands.  They linked the wikipedia article in which it specifically states "[Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade's] epilogue also reveals that "Indiana" is not Jones's first name, but a nickname he took from the family dog".  OP literally linked the answer in their question.

Comment: @T.J.L. It's also *in the movies*.

Comment: [They named *the dog* Indiana.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kO1MuJ_ijF8)

Comment: @jpmc26 Sure, going back to the original source material is always best. My point, however, was that the user linked to a summary that *also* gave the answer. In effect, the user is asking "Can somebody please read this article I linked to?"

Comment: @doc "I want to know the back story for a character in a film but I haven't watched all the films" sounds like a lack of research to me  The next question he will ask is "what is the relationship between luke skywalker and Darth Vader"

Answer (score 81, accepted):

It seems to be a name he gave himself when he was much younger. No date is given but, as I recall, he was nicknamed Indiana in the TV show [*The Young Indiana Jones Chronicles* (1992-93)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Young_Indiana_Jones_Chronicles)

We find out the origin of the name in [*Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade* (1989)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097576/)

> Sallah: Please — what is always with this "Junior"?
>
> Henry Jones Sr.: That's his name: "Henry Jones, Junior."
>
> Indiana Jones: I like "Indiana."
>
> Henry Jones: We named the dog Indiana.
>
> Marcus Brody: May we go home now, please?
>
> Sallah: The dog? You are named after the dog? [laughs]
>
> Indiana: [coldly] I've got a lot of fond memories with that dog

---

As it turns out the *character* is, in fact, named after a dog

> But it's true. Indiana was the name of an Alaskan malamute George Lucas owned in the '70s.
>
> <sup>[Source](http://mentalfloss.com/article/18687/10-awesome-indiana-jones-facts)</sup>

Comment: Isn't this line **We named the dog Indiana** means that dog get named Indiana after the Jones Jr.?

Comment: Nope....the dog was called Indiana and Jr took that as a nickname.

Comment: Thanks.. That Lucas' dog reference made more sense.

Comment: I belive that clip is actually from *Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade*, not *the Young Indiana Jones Chronicles*, as your answer currently implies. (Which only makes it "more" canon.)

Comment: The video game _Indiana Jones and the Fate of Atlantis_ has a character who mentions a number of times that Indiana was named after the family dog.

Comment: @Vishwa it can be inferred from the exchange between Sally and Indiana ("You are named after the dog?" "I've got a lot of fond memories with that dog") that Indiana took the dog's name as his own nickname, not the other way around.

Comment: The physical appearance of [Indiana](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/7/7a/Lucasindiana.JPG/revision/latest?cb=20080909213850), the real one, was the inspiration for [another well-known Lucas character](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/4/48/Chewbacca_TLJ.png/revision/latest?cb=20171231005834).

Answer (score 20):

According to [the wikia page for the dog](http://indianajones.wikia.com/wiki/Indiana):

> The puppy Indiana was given to young Henry Jones, Jr. by his parents
>   Anna and Henry Sr. while still in the crib at their home in Princeton,
>   New Jersey.
>
> Jones had such affection for the Alaskan Malamute that he considered
>   his best friend, he adopted the name as his own growing up, calling
>   himself "Indiana" by 1905.

The information is derived from [*Indiana Jones: The Ultimate Guide*](http://indianajones.wikia.com/wiki/Indiana_Jones:_The_Ultimate_Guide), a 2008 reference book written by James Luceno, and from ["My First Adventure"](http://indianajones.wikia.com/wiki/My_First_Adventure), the first film in [*The Adventures of Young Indiana Jones*](http://indianajones.wikia.com/wiki/The_Adventures_of_Young_Indiana_Jones).

Comment: We may note in passing that Marion Morrison (more widely known by a stage name) likewise took his nickname ‘Duke’ from a dog.

Comment: This answers **Why** and **When** he adapted the name for himself. Thanks